# Printing Request id for every request

Tags: java, logging

Im trying to set requestId for each request in log4j logger files

I have the following configuration in filter class

```
MDC.put("requestId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

and I set this in application.property file

```
logging.pattern.level=%X{requestId}%5p
```

However, it is printing requestId in console output but not printing in the log file. Anything Im missing?

Comment: Is the log file being created and printing other logs?

Comment: Yes I get other details like Date, Log Level, Message etc

Comment: Can u post your application.properties file here? If you are unit testing post the test application.properties

Comment: also post the log.properties file

Comment: Got it working !! When you guys asked for property file I noticed my mistake. I didnt add the configuration in "logging.pattern.file" ... It is working now. Thank you.